# Why is the Black Pearl partially unharmed at the begining of "At World's End"?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, at-worlds-end

At the end of "Dead man's chest":

> The Kraken drags the Black Pearl and Captain Jack Sparrow down to Davy Jones' locker

Leading to his crew and friends to go after him in "At World's End". They arrive at the end of the world and fall down to Davy Jones' locker with their ship wrecked to pieces.

The Black Pearl is not broken to pieces **but it is still damaged on some parts** as can be seen here:

[image]

I assume it is not possible to repair the Pearl because you would have to use burned wood or otherwise it would stick out.

*My question is:* is there any explanation as to why was the Pearl in **almost** perfect shape when other boats remain destroyed after passing onto Davy Jones' locker?

Comment: May be Davy Jones instructed kraken to just move ship into his locker without harming jack, he wanted to punish jack, not kill him.jack was on the ship, so kraken made sure ship was as less as harmed as possible, I'm saying, just maybe

Comment: We see the Kraken's tentacles wreaking havoc inside the Captain's chamber which is undamaged when we see it again in the 3rd movie.

Comment: "when other boats remain destroyed after passing onto Davy Jones' locker" What is your basis for this? Other boats we see the kraken attack aren't being sent to the Locker, they're being destroyed. In Jack's case, though, Davy Jones is specifically after his soul. He sends him and his ship to the hell/limbo that is the Locker. Having the ship intact, but useless in the desert, is a cruel punishment.

Comment: Jack's friends coming to save him. The ship they took to the World's end is broken apart. I'd assume that the World's end is the main entrance to the Locker rather than the Kraken's mouth so it wouldn't make much sense that a Kraken-eaten ship is restored and not even entirely.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that Jack was in **hell**. You can argue that the locker is more like purgatory/limbo; but regardless of that discussion, Jack was clearly put in a situation that was meant to **torment** him.

Jack has the Pearl, but he's stuck in a desert and there's no wind. For someone like Jack, who lives to sail on the ocean, this is the worst that could happen. Eternity without sailing.
**Before** the gang show up (at least before Jack knows about it), the stone crabs had already put the Pearl back into the water. But there was still no wind, so the Pearl was still dead in the water.

Jack's torment seems **intentional**, not coincidental. That means that whoever created this environment (Davy Jones? A higher power?) would likely also have chosen to give Jack the Pearl to make it even more aggravating.

This means that the Pearl (in the locker) is not necessarily the **actual** Pearl, but rather a **recreation** of the Pearl (as Jack knows and loves it).

*Note: it's also possible that the original Pearl was taken to the locker and then fixed by whoever designed Jack's torment; instead of creating a new Pearl from scratch.*

And when the gang succeed in extracting Jack from the locker, they also succeed in extracting this recreated/fixed Pearl into the real world.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point for the Pearl being with Jack in the Locker is to basically mock Jack and drive him mad. Jack is a pirate who loves his ship and the sea, so why take both, when you could have the Pearl forever stuck on dry land?

As people say, it may not be the real Black Pearl, and it could be a recreation. But if it is a recreation, you would have to know how it looked when the Kraken took Jack and the Pearl to the locker. And we see the damage from the Kraken and the attack from the Dutchman from Pirates 2: Dead Man’s Chest.

As I believe, the reasoning behind this was that Jones wanted to torment Jack, to torture him, to satisfy his debt. But to have the wreck of the Pearl with Jack? That isn’t giving the same results.

Also, the Pearl could be mostly unharmed for the simplest of reasons: PLOT CONVENIENCE. Remember how later in the film, during one of the deleted scenes, we see Jack and Barbossa talking in the Captain’s Cabin. Barbossa says that Jack isn’t keeping the Pearl in good shape, and Jack points to the massive hole in the back, and says it’s ventilation.

What it actually is, however, is that the hole in the back of the cabin was due to the damage taken from the Dutchman. We see the damage to the gun ports from the tentacles, the destroyed lantern on the back, and the rim of the ship is smashed up.

Now, to answer the question on why the Pearl is MOSTLY unharmed is basically what the user from years ago posted: it wasn’t damaged when the Kraken took it under. It was still (somewhat) intact.

Feel free to downvote this answer, I may be wrong. But I’m feeling good about this response due to the fact that I love these films.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logic in posting an extremely long answer that just boils down to "I agree with that one user from years ago". Can you make it clearer what this adds to... whichever answer it is that you're referring to? Note that Stack Exchange is a strict Q&A site, not a discussion forum, so answers should be standalone and not rely on other answers.

Answer (score -1):

Jack had a lot of time to do nothing but repair it. Being a top tier pirate ship, it would make sense that it would be fully laden with spare parts and supplies in storage even when it went under.

Comment: This feels like a total guess. Can you back it up with any evidence?

Comment: Other than the movie itself literally?

Answer (score -2):

I think I know the answer. Let's look at it like this. When we see the kraken take down the pearl, did it crush our favourite ship? No, no it did not.
The Black Pearl may be a powerful ship, with its speed and firepower, but it's not invincible. The Pearl was not repairs, nor destroyed, it was just pulled under the water.
The Pearl we see has all the same damage to the cabin, stern lantern and other damage. It is the same ship. Of course, I could be entirely wrong, but my answer is likely to be accurate.
So long story short: the Pearl was not destroyed, it was just pulled under

Answer (score -3):

**Preface:** The following is a mostly speculative answer, but one that I would argue is logical and will try and support it with other *POTC*-related media. The problem lies in that *POTC* is an ongoing franchise, which may be working towards a redemption arc for Captain Jack Sparrow and includes each film digging deeper into Jack's past and ultimately is building some origin mythologies. So there could be a more solid answer down the line.

The Black Pearl was formerly The Wicked Wench and belonged to Captain Morgan. We also learn from *DMTNT* that Morgan was also the previous owner/user of Jack's MAGICAL compass. At some point, Morgan fights against Spanish Royal Armada and his ship ends up in Davy Jones Locker. Jack later makes a deal with Davy Jones, that includes a life-debt of a 100 souls (or his) for the ship to be risen and rechristened The Black Pearl. So we could assume a couple of things.

1. The ship previously had magical properties, as POTC-Wiki sites the Wicked Wench as a "legendary" ship and The Black Pearl as a "ghost" ship, therefor, it may be that Davy Jones (alone) could not ever fully destroy this ship, he can only take it out of commission. Also, why else would Jack want this ship, if it wasn't already special?
2. Davy Jones Locker is a magical space where most things are not destroyed, but only if he (or any Dutchman Captain?) is the one to put people and objects in there. The reason I say that is because clearly, the ship used by Barbossa, Elizabeth, and Will (*AWE*) does not make it, at least not that we know of (it's possible that Davy Jones Locker is vast and we have only seen a small part of it)--but that could have to do with the entry way, more than just that everyone who dies goes to the Locker, as we know most people are "suppose" to get ferried to some "other side". This is a responsibility of any Captain of the Flying Dutchman.

> The Black Pearl was an infamous pirate ship, originally named the
> Wicked Wench. At one point it was sold and turned into a merchant
> vessel before turning back to piracy when it was **re-christened**. With
> sails as dark as a moonless night, and a hull painted to match, this
> legendary ship of the seven seas was every inch a pirate vessel. Built
> for action, this **ghost ship** could outsail any other sailing vessels...
>
> **The Wench's first captain was Morgan, a pirate who died in a battle
> with the Spanish Royal Navy.** Command was later given to Jack Sparrow,
> who led the Wench and her crew on several voyages from West Africa to
> the Caribbean and back for the East India Trading Company on the
> behalf of Cutler Beckett. However, after Jack liberated a cargo of
> slaves, Beckett ordered the Wench set alight and sunk and her captain
> forever branded as a pirate. After failing to rescue the Wench, Jack
> made a deal with Davy Jones, the ghostly captain of the Flying
> Dutchman. Jones raised the Wicked Wench from the depths, giving Jack
> thirteen years as captain, in exchange for one hundred years of
> service aboard the Dutchman. http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Pearl
>
> At some point in his life Morgan became a captain of a pirate ship
> called the Wicked Wench. **The Wicked Wench and her crew were part of
> the pirate fleet that tried to end Armando Salazar's reign** of terror
> when the villainous Spanish capitán attempted to clean the seas from
> piracy. In a fierce battle off the coast of the mysterious Devil's
> Triangle the last pirates in the Caribbean joined forces in an attempt
> to sink Salazar's ship, the dreaded Silent Mary, but the mighty
> warship and her crew proved to be unstoppable.[3]
>
> Soon, most of the pirate fleet was burning and sinking, and the Wicked
> Wench was the only pirate ship left afloat. Mortally wounded when the
> broadside from the Silent Mary hit the Wench's quarterdeck, Morgan
> gave his compass to Jack, an 18-year old boy, telling him never to
> betray it.[3] http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Morgan

**Some Trivia that may support #1 - The Wicked Wench was already "magical."**

In addition some trivia that might be of interest includes the canceled video game, a prequel, **Pirates of the Caribbean: Armada of the Damned.** The Game featured a new protagonist, Captain James Sterling who gets "cursed" by **"Cursed Spanish Ghost Pirates"** from a previous era. In the game, Sterling was to "reassemble" a **magical** **wrecked and scattered Pirate Ship called, the Nemesis** --AND depending on the choices one would make, Sterling would become a good-looking heroic legendary pirate or he would become feared and dreaded and turn into a ghostly-dark pirate who used a GIANT ANCHOR as a weapon!!

> It is unknown who was the original captain of the Nemesis, but some
> time after his resurrection, captain Sterling has found the wreck of
> the Nemesis on some beach[2]. He decided to save the craft and turn it
> into his own pirate ship[3]. **Pieces of the Nemesis were scattered all
> around the Caribbean,** and Sterling spent many months in search of
> them.

A LOT of the game's elements seemed to be built back into the franchise, especially *Dead Men Tell No Tales* with Salazar in particular looking a lot like the "evil" version of Sterling and similar character to the games villain, Admiral Maldonado. **The Black Pearl's anchor** is featured also, as Carina Smith climbs up it!

> A nameless pirate with an anchor on his back, member of the Drifting
> Dead, can be seen in Davy Jones' Locker in At World's End (video
> game).

In one of the other already-existing POTC video games, there is a GIANT ANCHOR seen in Davy Jones locker--some speculate there would of been a correlation between The Spanish cursed Pirates, Sterling, and Davy Jones, but no one will ever know since the game was never released, only beta-tested, but it's possible that they are taking these ideas and re-contextualizing them back into the newer parts of series with Morgan and his Magic Ship being a kind of equivalent with Sterling and his magic ship and that Jack's Sparrow's story relies on the history of Morgan and his magical objects.

Comment: This seems to be mostly speculative, but more importantly, seems to deviate away from the question about halfway down. That cancelled game looks cool, but what does it have to do with the question? You seem to talk about it more than you talk about a possible answer.

Comment: I'm suggesting they made Sterling into Morgan and therefor the Pearl or Wicked Wench is likely a legendary ship that already had super powers and that might be why Davy Jones couldn't just destroy it---there is a REASON Jack wanted this ship back from the same person who have him the compass. The games ideas support the theory, because they are matching things seen in the newer cannon...

Comment: Its not canon; it never came out. This still seems to rely entirely on *fan theory*.

Comment: You misunderstand, I never said the game was cannon, what I am saying is that elements from the game are being reworked into the new cannon  (POTC:DMTNT +) I was just attempting one possible speculative answer through commonality between the works, but we may not get a better answer YET since Jack Sparrow's redemption arc is NOT finished and other films may dig deeper when doing so. Nobody else really tried, so I did, because there are similarities from the game and DMTNT

Comment: I'm homing in on the idea that The Nemesis and The Wicked Wench/Black Pearl may be in similitude or parallel, as Sterling is with Morgan and therefor the ship may not be destructible by Davy Jones alone and that is why it was still in tact in his Locker and WHY Jack wanted Morgan's ship to begin with, because it has magical proprieties prior to Jack's dealings with Davy Jones.